# View Power BI Embed Report using Single Sign on

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, powerbi-embedded

we have our existing web application which will be used by our internal users.

Azure AD Authentication is being used to login into the App.

we need to embed the reports in web app and it should be accessing bel to logged in user without separate authentication.

i see we can use power bi embed for your organization for internal users but it still requires user login explicitly.

Please let me know best option to use azure AD single sign on to access power bi reports in my web app

I am expecting to use azure AD single sign on to access power bi reports in my web app

Comment: Your users shouldn't need to log in again if they log into your app with Azure AD.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , in order to archive this what steps i need to follow
Do i need to enable the single sign on anywhere or grant permission for the power bi API in Azure AD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user's login to the app for the first time, you can get the access Token in response.

For Embedding any report, we need embed URL and access Token.

You can get the access Token from the above and it will be of token Type AAD.

Use this accessToken as Bearer token to hit the [Get Report in Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports-in-group) REST API to get the Embed URL.

Comment: If you still have question, rephrase your question, which lang is your web application is and which msal libraries you're using for signing.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , do we need to Add scopes for  Power BI Service in Azure AD ?

Comment: Yes, We need to add scopes in our Azure AD App.

Comment: ya it worked by adding scope and using https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default